# How to call javascript function from html without using any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set value of a div by calling a javascript function. below is the divs(for rating) in a gridview.

in the below code the function is called from value="" but it is not working

Is it possible to call a javascript function from html other than on an event (other than onclick etc..)

What is the other alternative for doing this

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="rateit" id="divrate1"></div>rate1
                    <br /><div class="rateit" id="divrate2"></div>rate2
                    <br /><div class="rateit" id="divrate3"></div>rate3
                    <br />Rate<div class="rateit" id="divrate4"></div>rate4


                    <input type="hidden" id="test2" runat="server"   value="javascript:SetRates(
                            '<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>',
                            '<%#Eval("Rev1","{0}")%>',
                            '<%#Eval("Rev2","{0}")%>',
                            '<%#Eval("Rev3","{0}")%>',
                            '<%#Eval("Rev4","{0}")%>');return false;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

javascript function

```
function SetRates(RowIndx,vRt,uRt,dRt,nRt){

        RowIndx=parseInt(RowIndx)+1;
        var drvDiv=$(document.getElementById('<%=GridView2.ClientID %>').rows[RowIndx]).find('.rateit');
        $(drvDiv[0]).rateit('value', vRt);
        $(drvDiv[1]).rateit('value', uRt);
        $(drvDiv[2]).rateit('value', dRt);
        $(drvDiv[3]).rateit('value', nRt);
        $(drvDiv[3]).rateit('readonly',true);
        return 1;
     }
```

btw where can i find documentation for negative marks for a query in SO?

Comment: `value="javascript:SetRates`. Is it a typo? I think It should be `onclick="javascript:SetRates`

Comment: no it is value only . i am trying to set some values without user clicking any button

Comment: do a `console.log(...)` and see what the values of the parameters are in the `SetRates` function. My guess is that `parseInt` is failing.

Comment: but the function works correct when it is called in the onclick using test1 button

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the javascript function on a different action like  for example "onchange". Not sure if for value property of a type hidden works like that.

Comment: OK I tried it now. but still it gives the same syntax error "The server tag is not well formed." But i cant see any syntax error in code